# Grails application doesn't start in debug mode

Tags: grails

A grails application i work on can not start on debug mode. During start up, the application waits endlessly after the first "Running Grails application" message. Waited for a very long time but no error message is given. What can i do to find the source of the problem? With debug mode turned off, project starts. Tried with grails 2.3.6 and 2.4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application is probably waiting for the remote debugger to connect.  That is by design. Once you connect the remote debugger the process should continue the startup procedure.

Comment: No, I tried with both commenting forked execution mode (old style single jvm process) and new forked mode with remote debugger attached. In both cases project stucks during start up. I don't have such problem with other projects.

Comment: In general debugging works.  I do it all the time.  I expect there is something peculiar in your project that is relevant but without seeing the project that is difficult to say for sure.  If you can identify whatever it takes to reproduce the problem, please file a JIRA at https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS and we will straighten it out.